# Cannot delete iMessages

Tags: messages

Ever since updating to new operating system I cannot delete iMessages from my iPad. I had an Ipad 2 and bought a new iPad Air 2 today, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: You say 'Ever since updating to new operating system' - which operating system update are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

To delete one or more iMessages from a conversation, tap & hold one message until the **Copy | More** float appears, then tap More.
You can than add or remove checkmarks from individual messages in that conversation & delete using the trash can, bottom left.

To delete an entire thread, from the overview drag the thread name to the left - a delete button will appear on the right.